# how to solve invalid number of sections while sorting an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, sorting

im trying to sort an array of date by Date the method works fine until I added this method `self.TableView.insertSections(IndexSet(arrayindex), with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)`
and i got `NSInternalInconsistencyException` err, my `numberOfSections return 1`, i have only one section

here is the compiler message

```
reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted).'
```

***my code***

```
var DriverOffers = [driverOrdersData]() {
        didSet {
            DriverOffers = DriverOffers.sorted(by: <)
        }
    }

func sort() {

let offer = driverOrdersData(userUid: userid, name: name, phone: phone, amount: price, time: time, marketName: marketName, storeImg: img, userImg: userImg, date: date, orderDetails: order, orderLocation: orderLoc, userLocation: userlocation, distance1: self.distance1!, distance2: self.distance2! )

self.DriverOffers.append(offer)
self.DriverOrdersTV.reloadData()

//my problem is here where the app start to crash
let arrayindex = [self.DriverOffers.firstIndex(of: offer) ?? 0]                                   
self.DriverOrdersTV.insertSections(IndexSet(arrayindex), with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
}

extension driverOrdersData: Comparable{
    static func < (lhs: driverOrdersData, rhs: driverOrdersData) -> Bool {
        return lhs.date < rhs.date
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: driverOrdersData, rhs: driverOrdersData) -> Bool {
        return lhs.date == rhs.date
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After we execute the first insert method, the actual number of rows in the data source is one more than the number of rows on the UI, which is not equal. Cause a crash.
Integrate the insert or delete operation between beginupdates method and endupdates method to perform only one UI update.
try like this:

```objectivec
self.DriverOrdersTV.beginUpdates()
//my problem is here where the app start to crash
let arrayindex = [self.DriverOffers.firstIndex(of: offer) ?? 0]
self.DriverOrdersTV.insertSections(IndexSet(arrayindex), with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            
self.DriverOrdersTV.endUpdates()
```

more info you can see [enter link description here](https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_37389821/article/details/106961953)

Comment: after deleting a row I also face the same issue, how to detect that deletion of table view row

Comment: `self.DriverOrdersTV.beginUpdates()
                                                    self.DriverOrdersTV.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                                                    self.DriverOrdersTV.endUpdates()` this one works actually, thanks for pointing out on `beginUpdates() & endUpdates()`